# Run Jquery code once on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 form fields (hex color) that are activated when the user click in them.

If the user is editing an existing data set, then i load the colors and show them in the field right when the page loads. How do i run the script when the page is loaded so i display the right colors beside the field?

So how do i run `$('#colorpicker1').colpick()` and `$('#colorpicker2').colpick()` when page loads?

The script i'm running is http://colpick.com/plugin (example #1, but with data ALREADY in field when page loads)

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function (){

$('#colorpicker1').colpick({
        layout:'hex',
        submit:0,
        onChange:function(hsb,hex,rgb,el,bySetColor) {
            $(el).css('border-color','#'+hex);
            // Fill the text box just if the color was set using the picker, and not the colpickSetColor function.
            if(!bySetColor) $(el).val(hex);
        }
    }).keyup(function(){
        $(this).colpickSetColor(this.value);
    });


    $('#colorpicker2').colpick({
        layout:'hex',
        submit:0,
        onChange:function(hsb,hex,rgb,el,bySetColor) {
            $(el).css('border-color','#'+hex);
            // Fill the text box just if the color was set using the picker, and not the colpickSetColor function.
            if(!bySetColor) $(el).val(hex);
        }
    }).keyup(function(){
        $(this).colpickSetColor(this.value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Like the document ready function: `$(function() { ... });`?

Comment: Why u can not using $(document).ready() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the plunker referred, the JS & CSS for the colorpicker has been taken from the  site you linked.

http://plnkr.co/edit/nYSY6b7JJwdHXJ7SmcdP?p=preview

Ideally this pattern would solve your problem-

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $(".className").colpick({
  /*
     Inner Code.
  */
  });
});
</script>
```

**EDIT:**
Okay, so your problem is not related to plugin.
Take a look at the updated plunker- http://plnkr.co/edit/nYSY6b7JJwdHXJ7SmcdP?p=preview

```
$.each($('.colorpicker'),function(){
      $(this).css('background','#'+$(this).val());
});
```

This will solve your problem, since the plugin doesn't have any convenient methods/options available.

**EDIT - Final solution**

To load the colors already in the input field, and activate the script correctly, here's how to do it:

```
 $.each($('.colorpicker'),function(){
        //init code
        var defCol = $(this).val();
        $(this).css('border-color','#'+defCol);
        //plugin
        $(this).colpick({
            layout:'hex',
            submit:0,
            color: defCol,
            onChange:function(hsb,hex,rgb,el,bySetColor) {
                $(el).css('border-color','#'+hex);
                // Fill the text box just if the color was set using the picker, and not the colpickSetColor function.
                if(!bySetColor) $(el).val(hex);
            }
        }).keyup(function(){
            $(this).colpickSetColor(this.value);
        });
    });
```

Comment: ok sorry if i didn't explain well enough. I looked at your plunker code and if we add a default value like this `<input type="text" class="colorpicker" value="ff0000" />`, i want the code to run on startup and show the border of the field as "RED". (when you use the color picker manually, it updates the border color with the color you chose)

Comment: Have just changed the attribute from border-color to background to illustrate the point better.

Comment: Although this is not perfect for this precise situation, this is the best answer. I just changed the `background` to `border-color`. The only little bug is that when i click in the pre-defined field (red), the colorpicker script still defaults my color as something else then the ff0000 i want. But its minor. Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome. I have a new plunker- http://plnkr.co/edit/geEqP4qvTpP9QSdGOqye?p=preview
which i believe is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#colorpicker1, #colorpicker2').colpick()
});
```

Try this:

Comment: this does not work... the script im running is this: http://colpick.com/plugin (example #1, with data ALREADY in field)

Comment: @Joel Yes it does. It means you did someone wrong on your side. And "It does not work" is not helpful. How could we help you if you refuse to say what's wrong?

Comment: sorry for the lack of precision. I've updated my question above. When i run your code it just does nothing. Here's the thing: i pre-fill the field with a color, ex: "000000". Then when the page load, i want the script to run, see the color and does what it does when you manually click in the field, which is display the color beside the field. With your code, nothing happens, so i'm clueless on how to run that script...

Answer (score 0):

`$( document ).ready()` is whay you need.

Use it this way:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){

  // the document is ready now, do stuff here

});
```

[$( document ).ready() | jQuery Learning Center](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery give  onload or ready fuction to excute the script on load -

$(document).ready(function() {

```
  alert("document ready occurred!");
```

});

$(window).load(function() {

```
  alert("window load occurred!");
```

});

Answer (score 0):

To execute some functions when the document is ready use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#colorpicker1').colpick()
    $('#colorpicker2').colpick()
})
```